# Please recommend a good OpenStreetMap component

Tags: c#, java, netbeans, openstreetmap

I've been asked to write an internal application for our business that uses mapping functionality to place push-pins of business related data.

As this is not a public facing application and to be used by a single person within our firewall I can not use google maps as we do not have the funds for the google license.

I am investigating the use of [OpenStreetMap](http://www.openstreetmap.org/) and can either embed a component into an already existing WPF application or embed into an existing WPF application, a NetBeans platform based application or into a new web application.

Could someone please suggest a library for use in either of these environments?

Comment: I've used [`JMapViewer`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer).

Comment: @trashgod: thanks, I have had a hard crack at that one and now have settled on the `JXMapKit` control from [spring-ws](http://java.net/projects/swingx-ws/) which is turning out pretty nice, though I had to modify it a bit to get multiple tile servers loading (like a, b, c from OSM). Put your comment as an answer!

Comment: Just to throw there another option, I use swingx-ws and I'm happy with the results. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314468/slippy-maps-for-java-swing-guis-swingx-ws

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently updated [`JMapViewer`](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/JMapViewer) from r26523 to r26975 without incident. Subjectively, it seems faster.

Comment: Thanks trashgod, I've experimented with both JMapViewer and JXMapViewer of which I like both, I do like the JXMapKit though with it's built in controls, there are however some things I didn't like so I've downloaded the source and want to contribute back some changes, in particular the multiple tile host support which I've now completed.

Answer (score 1):

I've recently started to build a WPF prototype using [SharpMap](https://github.com/sharpmap/sharpmap) - although it's currently migrating to V2 and some of the dataproviders are missing - so I've been using V1 which has support for BruTile. You also might find [BruTile](https://github.com/BruTile/BruTile) useful.

Comment: A good tool, but a bit more work by the seems. From my evaluation it seems you need to host your own tile server.

Comment: @Brett: Any pointers on how to do that? Maybe you can mention them in _your_ answer. :-)