# Is there any [un]official info about SwingX-WS 1.1 and its development status?

Tags: java, swing, maps, openstreetmap, swingx

I've been keeping an eye for almost a year on [swingx-ws](http://java.net/projects/swingx-ws) (on [SwingX](http://swinglabs.org/) website, via Google and whatnot [[1](http://wiki.java.net/bin/view/Javadesktop/SwingLabsSwingXWS),[2](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.swinglabs/swingx-ws), etc.]), to see if version 1.1 eventually made it to become a released milestone (I'm using [v1.0](http://swinglabs.org/downloads.jsp) but there are some JXMapViewer bugs that, according to [JIRA](http://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX_WS), are being addressed in v1.1).

Am I looking in the wrong places? Is development still active?

(If you can suggest a nice alternative library for dealing with online maps in Swing that you particularly like, please do)

EDIT: see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314468/slippy-maps-for-java-guis-swingx-ws) for an update.

Comment: Pleas provide link(s) to what you've been following.

Comment: Sure! I'll add links tomorrow (I can't now because I'm on my smartphone and cannot copy&paste)

Comment: Re maps, see also this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7911054/230513).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818528

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that SwingX 1.6.4 is out, SwingX-WS support has been dropped altogether! Boo ...:(

What a pity... such a nice and useful tool abandoned. I'll end up embedding browser-based maps into desktop applications.

-EDIT-

JXMapViewer has been resurrected here: https://github.com/msteiger/jxmapviewer2

-EDIT bis-

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314468/slippy-maps-for-java-guis-swingx-ws) for an update.

Comment: hmm.. not really (are we impatient, aren't we ;-) - it wasn't officially supported for a long while. Simply grab the current sources, update to swingX 1.6.4 - and contribute back. Will be happy to commit in your name :-) Or maybe you want to maintain it, would be great?

Comment: Quite impatient indeed! :)
I will do what you suggest and play around with the sources, within the limits of my current Swing knowledge. If I succeed in my tinkering, well, I might propose to maintain it.

Comment: Cool! Feel invited to pass me a note if you are ready or run into problems :-) And/or comment the [swingx issue](http://java.net/jira/browse/SWINGX-1524) you created.

Comment: One quick question @kleopatra: could you suggest me some reading material (if there's any) to better understand the differences (and the different domains of use) between JMapViewer and JXMapViewer? As far as I know, the second is based upon the former, it uses SwingX components, and it eases integration by providing wheels you don't need to reinvent yourself, am I right?

Comment: when it comes to ws, my knowledge is ... limited more than yours :-) Don't know.

Comment: good to know :-) BTW, updated swingx-ws recently to be in synch with current swingx (1.6.5-1), just forgot about this thread, sorry .... you can check-out the code from svn and compile locally.

Comment: @kleopatra you are the greatest!